# nginx /health endpoint without index.h

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-location

I'm trying to add a /health endpoint to a nginx server using the following config file

```
server {
    listen 8080 default_server;

    location /health {
        access_log off;
        return 200;
    }
}
```

I launch the container using the following command

```
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 -v "$PWD/health.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/health.conf" nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged:alpine
```

However nginx tries to load the file /usr/share/nginx/html/health/index.html when accessing localhost:8080/health

How can I avoid that and just return 200?